# NSIS Check if an empty directory exists

Tags: nsis

I need to check if an USB dongle has been inserted. I use the following code to do so:

```
!macro HAS_USB_DONGLE
  IfFileExists "E:\*.*" hasDongle 0
  MessageBox MB_OK "USB Dongle is not inserted. Please insert the USB dongle and re-run this installer."
Abort

  hasDongle:
!macroend
```

This however only works if there are any files (or directories) on E:. How can I check if an empty directory exists?

Comment: That syntax should work for normal directories but your example only has a drive letter. NSIS uses FindFirstFile internally and MSDN says "C:\*" etc is valid for a root directory...

Comment: Update: It did not always work. See my own solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a specific folder?

`IfFileExists` can be used with a file, a wildcard, or a **directory**.

```
!macro HAS_USB_DONGLE
  IfFileExists "E:\ThisIsTheFolderYouAreLookingFor" hasDongle 0
  MessageBox MB_OK "USB Dongle is not inserted. Please insert the USB dongle and re-run this installer."
Abort

  hasDongle:
!macroend
```

Comment: I did try that and it did not work. Although there might have been something else wrong at the point I tried that. Anyway, I belive the wildcard is obligatory. This is from the NSIS documentation:  _If you want to check to see if a file is a directory, use IfFileExists DIRECTORY\*.*_

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to perform it

```
!macro uni_isEmptyDir un
Function ${un}isEmptyDir
    # Stack ->                    # Stack: <directory>
    Exch $0                       # Stack: $0
    Push $1                       # Stack: $1, $0
    FindFirst $0 $1 "$0\*.*"
    strcmp $1 "." 0 _notempty
    FindNext $0 $1
    strcmp $1 ".." 0 _notempty
    ClearErrors
    FindNext $0 $1
    IfErrors 0 _notempty
    FindClose $0
    Pop $1                  # Stack: $0
    StrCpy $0 1
    Exch $0                 # Stack: 1 (true)
    goto _end
    _notempty:
        FindClose $0
    ClearErrors
    Pop $1                   # Stack: $0
    StrCpy $0 0
    Exch $0                  # Stack: 0 (false)
    _end:
FunctionEnd
!macroend

; make isEmptyDir function available both for installer and uninstaller
!insertmacro uni_isEmptyDir ""
!insertmacro uni_isEmptyDir "un."
```

Usage from the installer section:

```
Push "Path to check"
Call isEmptyDir
Pop $0
```

Usage from the uninstall section:

```
Push "Path to check"
Call un.isEmptyDir
Pop $0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this has become a popular question, I thought I'd post my own solution. The answers which I tried above were not reliable for me. I have not tested the solution provided by khayk, that may be the best one. In the end I solved the problem by creating a dummy file, checking if directory exists and then delete the dummy file. Hacky, but works well for my use.

```
!macro HAS_USB_DONGLE
  FileOpen $0 "$USB_DIR\dummy" w
  FileClose $0
  ClearErrors

  IfFileExists "$USB_DIR*" hasDongle 0
  MessageBox MB_OK "USB Dongle is not inserted. Please insert the USB dongle and re-run this installer."
  Abort

  hasDongle:
  Delete "$USB_DIR\dummy"
  ClearErrors
!macroend
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this function](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Check_if_dir_is_empty).

Also note, that your macro would not work. Macros are repeated code and you can't use the same label multiple times (within the same section/function).

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question, I don't really care if the directory is empty or not. Thanks for the label tips however, NSIS sure has many pitfalls.